# sublime text 3 After clicking rename folder and entering the name, it is invalid after entering enter？

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, file-rename

After clicking rename folder and entering the name, it is invalid after entering enter?

When I press enter it goes to the next line, unable to confirm the submission, the modification of the file directory/file

any sug will help!!

[image: Example of incorrect operation]

Comment: Are you sure you're using ST3 and not ST4? (What does `Help > About` say the build number is?). This problem happens in ST4 to people who have overridden the whole of the default key bindings, which makes the `enter` key behave as just inserting a newline in places where it's not supposed to.

Comment: this is my version: Copyright◎2006-2021 Sublime HQ Pty Ltd Stable Channel, Build 4126,I think it is st4 by opening the changelog, because of my ignorance, I always thought I installed sublime text 3. st4 4126 :https://www.sublimetext.com/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ST3, the behaviour of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in panels (e.g. the Find panel, the command palette, and the input panel and all other panels/inputs) was hard coded, but in ST4 it's not and instead <kbd>Enter</kbd> is bound to a command that triggers the action instead.

Overall, this means that everything is more flexible; you can choose the key combination that submits commands, plugins can programmatically control things in ways they could not before, etc.

The reason you're seeing this problem is that you have (either on purpose or accidentally) overriden the whole of the `Default` key binding set, effectively locking it into the bindings as they existed in a prior version of Sublime Text. As such, the bindings on the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key are not present in the file, so the key just does what it would normaly do in a text input, which is start a new line.

To resolve the problem, use `Preferences > Browse Packages` from the main menu or the command palette, which will open up the `Packages` folder in your OS's file system browser.

In that folder, either move away the `Default` folder entirely, or go inside of it and move away the `sublime-keymap` files, then quit and restart Sublime.

That will stop Sublime from seeing the overriden content so that the packed in defaults will apply again, and bring the appropriate bindings back.

Here you're moving the folder/files away so that if you happen to have any customizations in there that you're not aware of, you have a backup to be able to go in and find and restore the parts you want. You can also just remove them entirely if you're sure you don't need them.

Comment: Yes,it works when I remove default folder .I think reason is that  Using an unreasonable way to install plugins without package control long time ago ,anyway it works now ,thanks a lot